# Add references to objects to a list

Tags: c#, list, pointers

I have the following code:

```
Point a = new Point(3, 3);

List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

points.Add(a);

a = new Point(50,50);

a.X += 50;
```

But say I want the last two lines of code to also affect the value in the list; how would I go about doing this?
My guess would be to add pointers to the list? But I think even then "new Point(50,50);" would still not update the list's value?

Thanks

Comment: I realize that I can access the values directly in the list. But thats not what I want to do. I want to create a debugging window that keeps track of certain variables that I 'register' by adding them to the list. The variables that I want to keep track of are images that should be visible in my debugging window, so its makes no sense to use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need pointers. A reference to an object in the .NET world can be thought of as essentially equivalent to a pointer in the world of unmanaged code. Things get a little tricker when you add in the fact that there are both [value types and reference types](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html), but in this case, modifying the object, or the object's reference, directly in the array is sufficient.

So, you can do either of the following:

```
points[0] = new Point(50, 50);
```

or

```
points[0].X = 50;
points[0].Y = 50;
```

(although you should [probably get into the habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil) of treating structures as if they were immutable, so consider the above for example purposes only).

Comment: Actually if `points` is a `List<Point>` and not an array (as in the question), you can't do: `points[0].X = 50;` because it gives a compilation error: `Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.Point>.this[int]' because it is not a variable`

Answer (score 0):

You would access the value directly in the list:

```
points[0] = new Point(50, 50);
```